# Why store negative votes of people new to SO?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, new-users

I recently gained the privilege to vote down. Before this, every time I down voted something, the system said something like:

> Your down vote is stored and will be applied, as soon as you reach the reputation privilege

Now having reached this boundary I have some questions/observations:

1. I didn't earn the badge "Critic" (which you get on your first down vote). I do not really care, but this makes me suspicious, whether the downvotes are actually saved.
2. When were the negative votes counted against my daily number of allowed votes?
3. Does it make sense to store the negative votes of new users? People are only allowed to vote down, when they have learned, what is a good question. Why should we store the negative votes of new people. Maybe I do now understand, what a good post is and what not, but I probably didn't when I had lower reputation, so why store them?

The first two questions are just about curiosity, the third-one is the actually interesting one.

PS: No, I do not remember any post I voted negatively on, so I can't/don't know how to check this.

Comment: A vote is a vote. Once you have earned the privilege, and you use that privilege, it is just another vote. No, we won't hobble new users some more once they earned it. How else will they learn to take those votes seriously?

Comment: Your profile page shows a voting summary. You haven't downvoted anything yet (unless you *just* voted, the totals are cached for a while).

Comment: `Your down vote is stored and will be applied, as soon as you reach the reputation privilege` -- I think you misremember that message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you down vote the pop up currently says

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

This would imply that the down votes cast by new users do not change the score on the question.

After searching this site another question from last year states that it used to say

> Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 125 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

That would show that the policy has now changed and that it seems now not to be the case.

Comment: Yes, apparently missremembered/missinterpreted the wording

Comment: After searching this site it appears the wording has changed so you did remember it quite well.

Comment: The policy has not changed at all; the wording of the message changed because too many users understood the previous wording as the OP of the question above.

Comment: Really? I'm glad they changed it then as it does make it sound like they will all count once you gain 125 reputation.

Comment: See [Message for upvotes is misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271919) for the background of this change.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. I didn't earn the badge "Critic" (which you get on your first down vote). I do not really care, but this makes me suspicious, whether the downvotes are actually saved.

Most badges aren't awarded immediately; you [have to wait](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298953/295232) a little bit. From my personal experience [(N=50)](https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts), the Critic badge takes at most an hour.

> 2. When were the negative votes counted against my daily number of allowed votes?

Only 'real' votes are counted; before you had this privilege, clicking the downvote button is stored as [anonymous feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98630/295232) and there is no rate limit for that.

> 3. Does it make sense to store the negative votes of new users? People are only allowed to vote down, when they have learned, what is a good question. Why should we store the negative votes of new people. Maybe I do now understand, what a good post is and what not, but I probably didn't when I had lower reputation, so why store them?

The tooltip on the downvote button says 'this question/answer is not useful'. You're free to interpret this in multiple ways, one of them being 'this question/answer is not useful *to me*'. Don't you think even new users are able to judge that?

---

> Your down vote is stored and will be applied, as soon as you reach the reputation privilege

As [THZX mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354269/why-store-negative-votes-of-people-new-to-so#comment499628_354269), the wording is  (critically) different:

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.